# sharekit for cordova 2.2.0

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, sharekit

I am new to iOS development with phonegap,

im trying to use the sharekit plugin, i followed all the steps mentioned in the Readme (sharekit 2.0), but it is still not working, I have receive following 3 errors:

```
/..path../Plugins/ShareKitPlugin.m:31:63: Use of undeclared identifier 'SHKURLContentTypeWebpage'
/..path../Plugins/ShareKitPlugin.m:85:63: Use of undeclared identifier 'SHKURLContentTypeWebpage'
/..path../Plugins/ShareKitPlugin.m:102:63: Use of undeclared identifier 'SHKURLContentTypeWebpage'
```

The problem is that i can't find any sharekit working properly for cordova 2.2.0, as I conclude that the old version of this plugins doesn't support the new cordova 2.2.0.

any suggestion to get the latest plugin? or How to fix these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem using phonegap 2.7.0 and the latest sharekit and sharekitplugin from the repo. Add this line below the import statement. It compiles and the plugin works for me. I don't know for sure if this is right though.

```
#import "SHKMail.h"// Add below this statement
char *SHKURLContentTypeWebpage="text/html";
```

The plugin has not been updated for 2 years so this is probably an incompatibility with the new Sharekit.

Answer (score 0):

Did not get these errors myself. But just a quick tip. Did you follow the [wiki](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit)? Don't forget the first step, as downloading the plugin directly from the Github page doesn't include the submodules.

Comment: I've followed the steps but not working, same errors appears.